# DynamoDB data load after transforming files. Any AWS service like GCP Dataflow/Apache Beam?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, etl, google-cloud-dataflow, data-pipeline

*New to AWS*. I have a **requirement** to create a daily batch pipeline

1. Read 6-10 1GB+ CSV Files. (Each file is an extract of a table from a SQL db.)
2. Transform each file with some logic and join all files to create one item per id.
3. Load this joined data in a single DynamoDB table with an upsert logic.

**Current** approach I have started with is:
We have an EC2 available used for such tasks. So I am writing a python code to (1) read all CSVs, (2) convert to a denormalised JSON file and (3) import into Dynamodb using boto3

My **question** is that I am concerned if my data is "Big Data". Is processing 10GB data with a single Python script ok? And down the line if the file sizes become 10x, will I face scaling issues?
I have only worked with GCP in the past and in this scenario I would have used DataFlow to get the task done. So is there an equivalent in AWS terms? Would be great if someone can provide some thoughts. Thanks for your time.

Comment: It could be useful if you take a deeper look into the service AWS Data pipeline

Comment: Thank you I was looking at that but it's not being used in the org yet. I haven't worked with Hadoop so a bit intimidated with that as it uses EMR, I am just curious to know what data is big data. At what time a single threaded python code on a file becomes too big to become a candidate for Hadoop processing?

Comment: you are asking the right questions -- but, hey: if it's stupid and it works, it's not that stupid ;) -- sure, a single threaded python script is going to eventually hit a scaling cap and when you get there you will have to replace it. but more complex solutions may have more operational overhead; finally: don't be intimidated by EMR or "big data"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more appropriate equivalent of Dataflow in AWS is [Kinesis Data Analytics](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-analytics/), which [supports Apache Beam's Java SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/09/amazon-kinesis-data-analytics-now-supports-java-based-apache-beam-streaming-workloads/).

You can see an [example of an Apache Beam pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/java/examples-beam.html) running on their service.

Apache Beam is able to [write to DynamoDB](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/aws/dynamodb/DynamoDBIO.html).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using Spark (some re-usable pipeline in my company).

Answer (score 0):

The AWS equivalent to Google Cloud Dataflow is [AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/).  The documentation isn't clear but [Glue does write to DynamoDB.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56975381/7359502)